# Access (x,y) element of table in HTML with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to set the background color of some td in a table, finding them with their coordinates. I'm using this jQuery selector :

```js
$("#tabs-1 .edt tr:eq(" + x + ") td:eq(" + y + ")");
```

but it's "empty", and its parent is n.fn.init[0].

Here's my html :

```html
<div id="tabs-1">
    <table class='edt'>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            ...
        </tr>
        ...
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            ...
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Where am I wrong ?

Comment: Assuming the `x` and `y` values are valid, what you have should work: https://jsfiddle.net/dewdt4L2/

Comment: `eq()` is zero-based. I assume you know that...

Comment: Note that the coordinates of the first cell would be x=0, y=0 and *not* x=1, y=1...dont confuse on that

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6sab9s5c/ it's working if the x and y are valid.

Comment: I've 60 rows and 6 columns, and I tested it with (6,3).
The table is generated with javascript, and when I look at page source I see no <tr> or <td>. Don't understand why.

Comment: It works for me as well. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/zmppyk3r/). You should check for selector `#tabs-1 .edt` , if they are proper.

Comment: I'm using it in a JSP context. May it have an influence on it ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use eq like that. Following code should work:

```
$("tr").eq(0).children("td").eq(0);
```

Your code should be:

```
$("#tabs-1 .edt tr").eq(x).children("td").eq(y);
```